# How to record live video using camcorder?

Tags: usb, hdmi, webvideos, sdi

I need to conduct a video conference using professional video cameras. I will be recording and streaming 1080p video **[1]**. To that end, I need to stream live video from a professional video camera to my PC. Here are the requirements:

- The camera output is HDMI or SDI
- The computer input is USB3
- The delay between the time an event occurs and the moment it reaches the PC must be under 300ms.
- The camera must show up as a webcam to the PC.
- The PC will be running Windows or Linux.

Any ideas?

**[1]** I am aware of how much data is involved. Please assume that I have sufficient resources to do this.

Comment: Is the USB3 interface a hard and fast requirement?  PCI-E solutions would likely give better performance.  Any capture device that has [WDM Video Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) support will work as a web cam input.  Something like the Matrox MXO2 Mini would be one device that has such support and would get the job done, but it is PCI-e or thunderbolt.

Comment: @AJHenderson, Yes, USB3 is a hard requirement because the PC will likely be a laptop or tablet that does not accept add-on cards. I might be able to use an ExpressCard slot with the MXO2 but I'm holding out for a USB3-only solution for now.

Comment: yeah, I'm not aware of anything that is capable of doing what you need over USB3.  As I understand it, there are architecture issues that make USB architecture in general not really work well for such work.  I have not looked seriously in to it since USB3 came out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the Intensity Shuttle from Blackmagicdesign

http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/intensity/models/

This link has some additional info.

http://help.livestream.com/customer/portal/articles/577891-what-are-your-recommended-devices-

Comment: I purchased an Intensity Shuttle. It is **very** finicky. You must be running Windows 7 (not older, not newer) on a specific USB3 chipset with a sufficient amount of bandwidth (older computers will not work) and you must use a specific resolution/frame-rate otherwise you'll get a black screen. Assuming you get past all these hurdles, it'll work (at least under Skype).